# Hibernate annotation: one-To-one onDelete action cannot set to CASCADE

Tags: database, hibernate, annotations, hibernate-mapping, cascade

I would like to create two table USER and USERDETAIL to fulfill:

1. USERDETAIL have reference to USER table.
2. Operation on USER table do not need to aware of USERDEAIL table existence.

This should be one-to-one non bidirectional relationship.

The entity classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER")
public class User implements Serializable{  
    @Id 
    @Column(name="ID")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid") 
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")  
    private String id;  
    //...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="USERDETAIL")
public class UserDetail implements Serializable{    

    @Id 
    @Column(name="ID")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "gen") 
    @GenericGenerator(name = "gen", strategy = "foreign",
    parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "user"))
    private String id;

    @OneToOne(optional= false , targetEntity=User.class, cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    //@JoinColumn(name="foreign_id",referencedColumnName="ID")
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn   
    private User user;  
    //...
}
```

This create two table correctly and the USERDETAIL  have foreign key constraint that its primary key is refernece by USER's id. However, the on Delete action is `Restrict` but not `Cascade`. I cannot delete a row of USER because of this.

I am using MySQL Sever 5.1. It does not seem like it does not support on delete action is cascade. Because I can manually delete the constraint and add a new constraint that set to on delete is cascade and work as I expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have solved the problem.

First of all, I have follow http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-relationship-example-annotation/ to create oneToOne mapping entities.

However, when I start the Tomcat, it always throw `NullPointerException` on mapping. Therefore, I come up with my question entities and seem to work fine except the deletion.

I finally realize it is just a bug that hibernate-anoatation cause. I then use 3.4.0.ga version and follow the link again. By replace `@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)` (I don't know why using this, hibernate cannot create table) to

```
@GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid") 
@GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
```

it work as I expected.

Although there is no foreign-key constrain on the table, deleting owner (USER) table really can also delete the child (USERDETAIL) table correctly with hibernate handle.

I also do not need to worry about update owner table with no child field on it. The `mappedBy` side actually has no physical mapping defined as Khue Vu said. Hibernate is smart enough not to delete the relation.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER")
public class User implements Serializable{  
    @Id 
    @Column(name="ID")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid") 
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String id;  
    //...

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="userdetail_id")
    public UserDetail getUserDetail() {
      ...
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name="USERDETAIL")
public class UserDetail implements Serializable{    

    @Id 
    @Column(name="ID")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "gen") 
    @GenericGenerator(name = "gen", strategy = "foreign",
    parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "user"))
    private String id;

    @OneToOne(optional= false , targetEntity=User.class, mappedBy = "userDetail")
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn   
    private User user;  
    //...
}
```

Basically, I suggest to make it bidirectionaly, with User class is the owner (by using mappedBy in UserDetail class). That way, when you delete a user, user detail will be deleted.

Comment: Sorry for not giving enough information. Because the user class would also be the Command object submitted by form input.I do not want to place the whole userdetail into the editform. This is the reason I do not want any reference on user class.

Comment: Can you set these UserDetail form field to hidden ? or modify the object before supplying it as the Command Object.

Comment: Yes I can set the field to be hidden. But isn't it a little bit too far to inject an whole object to the editform in order to maintain the relationship? The submit form do not need to change the userdatil table.

Comment: Hi, I found the document saying: `You don't have to (must not) define any physical mapping in the mappedBy side` [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-association) . Maybe you can just remove the attribute in User and still use `mappedBy` in UserDetail.

Comment: Yu. HI. I tried but it would create a new column on User table to ref UserDetail. Therefore, I do it reservely. To place mappedBy and PrimaryKeyJoinColumn on User class. A new column is created to ref User and it is reductant as I want the primarykey is also foreignkey ref to User. And the most important issue is the onDelete action is still Restrict and thus I still cannot delete a row on User.